# Weighted Chi-square

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

If X~$N(0,I_n)$ and A is a symmetric nxn matrix

Let $Q=X^TAX$. Then we know Q is chi-square iff A is idempotent matrix.  However can Q be weight chi square if A be any symmetric nxn matrix?

Weight Chi squares is $\sum_{I}a_iz_i^2$ where $z_i$ ~ N(0,1)

I try to express the $Q=X^TAX = \sum_{i=1}x_i^2A_{ii}+2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_jA_{ij}$ Then first sum will be weight Chi-square. The second sum will be some non-central chi-square. Then I got lost.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, you can write $A = R^\intercal R$ for some matrix $R,$ and then you have $Q = \|Rx\|^2 = \|y\|^2$ where $y \sim \mathsf{Norm}_n(0, A).$ Is this of any help?

Comment: What is your definition of "weighted chi-square"?

Comment: Why y~N(0,A) and then should Q be a weight chi-square?

Comment: @YinanLyu before asking questions about quadratic forms of Gaussian vectors, you should know about Gaussian vectors. Amongs the best well-known facts regarding them is that if $z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, \Sigma)$ then $Az + \mu \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, A^t\Sigma A).$

Comment: Actually, my formula is wrong. The variance of $Ax$ is $A \mathbf{D}(x) A^\intercal,$ where $\mathbf{D}(x)$ is the dispersion matrix (a.k.a. variance-covariance matrix) of $x.$ Then $\mathbf{D}(Rx) = \mathbf{E}(Rx(Rx)^\intercal) = \mathbf{E}(Rxx^\intercal R^\intercal) = R\mathbf{E}(xx^\intercal) R^\intercal = RR^\intercal = A^\intercal.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you  for give me this information. Then should $YY^T$ be some weight chi-square?

Comment: $YY^\intercal$ should be a Wishart matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution

Comment: $Y^\intercal Y$ should be a sum of weighted $\chi^2.$